# How do I read TankBall 2's interface?

Tags: tankball-2

Whenever I play TankBall 2, I can't help but notice the mysterious numbers at the top left of the screen...

[image: Bold. Stylish. Different. Plato's ideal form of the game interface.]

I figured out pretty quickly that the red bar with the time in it represents the amount of time remaining in the game, but I can't make heads or tails of the numbers above it. How should I read this interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blue numbers indicate your own *offensive* performance:

> **Hits** (points) / **Kills**

The red numbers indicate your own *defensive* performance:

> **Times hit** / **Deaths**

The red bar indicates your current health, and the numbers inside of it indicate how much time is left in the current game.

---

Also, the large tank icon, when clicked, will open up the team selection menu.  The grey arrow down by the chat will also open this menu when clicked.

Comment: Perhaps it's the amount of hits you have taken and the amount of times you have died? That's the best guess I have.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea.  I'll find out.